# Anyone has an example in cypress that uses Google login

Tags: google-signin, cypress

I need to write a cypress test for my app which uses federated login (Google). I am getting CORS error even after I have disabled chromeWebSecurity. Does anyone have any sample code for that?

```
describe('log in with google', ()=>{
  it('should work', ()=>{
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/')
    cy.contains('Log in with Google').click()
    cy.get("input#identifierId").type('gohawks12x3@gmail.com{enter}');
    cy.wait(5000);
    cy.get("input[@type=password]").type('<Pwd>{enter}');
  })
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: For starters, are you trying to log in through the UI or programmatically?  You're mixing the two styles, `cy.request()` would imply programmatically, but using `cy.get().type()` is a UI action.

For us to help you better, post some more info and show us what your test is doing currently.

Comment: Thanks Brendan. I wanted to do it through UI - I originally had cy.visit instead of cy.request but running into cors issue. However even after I changed to .request and disabled chromeWebSecurity, I am still getting it.

Comment: `visit` and `request` are completely different.  `request` will not load the page in the browser.  You need to use `visit` to load the page.

Comment: so my code is like this: describe('log in with google', ()=>{
  it('should work', ()=>{
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/')
    cy.contains('Log in with Google').click()
    cy.get("input#identifierId").type('gohawks12x3@gmail.com{enter}');
    cy.wait(5000);
    cy.get("input[@type=password]").type('<Pwd>{enter}');
  })
}) but I am getting CypressError: Cypress detected a cross origin error happened on page load:

  > Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: Ahh I see what you're doing.  Cypress recommends against doing this for a variety of reasons.  Here's an answer from Brian Mann with a bit more info:  https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1380#issuecomment-368663427

Comment: bummer... thanks anyway! very much appreciated!!

Comment: I solved it for my usecase over [https://stackoverflow.com/a/74435696/2827300](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74435696/2827300) but be warned I still needed some manual steps to overcome Google 2FA

Answer (score 8):

There is a library called [cypress-social-login](https://github.com/lirantal/cypress-social-logins) which does just that. 
It's recommended by the cypress team and can be found on the [cypress plugin page](https://docs.cypress.io/plugins/index.html#authentication).

https://github.com/lirantal/cypress-social-logins

> This Cypress library makes it possible to perform third-party logins
>   (think oauth) for services such as GitHub, Google or Facebook.
>
> It does so by delegating the login process to a puppeteer flow that
>   performs the login and returns the cookies for the application under
>   test so they can be set by the calling Cypress flow for the duration
>   of the test.

Comment: Some of you maybe had such kind of issue: https://github.com/lirantal/cypress-social-logins/issues/44 ?

Comment: This library has a specific bug which is blocking google login (other logins still work to my knowledge) [https://github.com/lirantal/cypress-social-logins/issues/71#issuecomment-839047895](https://github.com/lirantal/cypress-social-logins/issues/71#issuecomment-839047895)

Answer (score 1):

I do have a workaround that might help you.

Long story short, I'm testing an angular 10+ application that requires the user to be logged in before accessing anything. Likewise, before running any of my tests I had to make sure a valid user is logged in.

1. So, the way I approach this problem was to create a test user with valid email/password that could access my application.
2. After spending 1 week researching with no success, I came up with the following  solution:

```js
/**
 * This spec needs to run first to make sure the user is logged in before accessing
 * the normal flow of the application. Renaming the file to '01_[filename]' does the trick :).
 */
describe('Google Login', () => {
  /**
   * 2nd param replaces the global config (cypress.dev.json) only in the scope of the current .spec.
   * Similar to: Cypress.config('baseUrl', 'https://accounts.google.com');
   */
  it('should input email and password', { baseUrl:  'https://accounts.google.com' }, function() {
        // Handling all errors and 'skipping' test to avoid global failure.
        cy.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
          console.error('Google Login -> uncaught:exception', err);
          // Skip test from https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/fundamentals__errors
          return false;
        });

        cy.visit('/servicelogin');

        cy.wait(3000);

        // Google Login Redirection: Email Input
        cy.url().should('contain', 'accounts.google.com')
          .get('input[type="email"]').type('your-email-here')
          .type('{enter}').wait(3000);

        // Google Login Redirection: Password Input
        cy.url().should('contain', 'accounts.google.com')
          .get('input[type="password"]').type('your-password-here')
          .type('{enter}').wait(3000);
      });
});
```

Please take a look at the `cy.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {` this was the trick. I don't really care about testing the Google login or the result of this test, it's completely irrelevant, I just need to make sure the user is logged in, that's all. So, if this test fails (and it will) I'm just skipping it.

Works on `"cypress": "^9.0.0"`.

Comment: This doesnt work for me, google says error 400 malformed and i should not try it again.

Comment: Hi  @LeviHeßmann could you elaborate a bit more? I don't think that error '400 malformed' has anything to do with that the spec is trying to achieve...  I can confirm the solution above is working for `"cypress": "^6.8.0`. I will update my answer with a solution that works on `"cypress": "^9.0.0"` as  well.

Comment: Hi @maya.js - Is it possible to bypass the 2-Step Verification that appears after inputting your credentials?

Comment: Hi @krisc! I don't think we can do that programmatically, especially if the email account is managed by someone else... The admin would have to specifically remove the 2FA for that particular account. BTW, I've noticed Cypress has now its own section to explain Google Authentication, it might be worth it to check it out: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/google-authentication